# Best way to version control WordPress template files?

Tags: version-control

The built-in ability to restore revisions of posts and pages in Wordpress is great.  Is there something that gives the same power to template files in the theme-editor?  Perhaps a plugin?

Comment: I find this idea interesting, but is this practical over using real full-featured version control?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Templates are only stored as files in the file system.  They are not stored in the database so there is no core functionality for versioning template files.  When you make changes, the file is overwritten with the changes.

The easiest route would be to use an existing version control solution (SVN,CVS,Git,Hg, etc.) and maintain the versioning separate from WordPress.

Comment: As per my comment I kinda agree on full featured version control. Just want to note that templates being stored in file system doesn't prevent from storing their revisions elsewhere. Anyway I don't think WP internal editor is important enough (yet?) for someone to bother with developing such functionality for it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such plugin out there to do this that I am aware of. But, this is an awesome idea for a plugin. When I get the time I might have a go at creating a theme / plugin versioning plugin that merely creates copies of itself so you can revert back after changes have been made. It wouldn't be overly complex like Git or SVN, but it would be useful.

Comment: If you do create a plugin, please share it with us here!

Comment: I will be sure to. I've started on a rough version of it now, but nothing to release just yet.

Comment: Hi Dwayne, just wanted to check in.  Any further updates on this plugin?

Comment: Nothing as of yet Carson. I've been super busy with a heap of work for a while + freelance. I sadly haven't had the chance to work on this awesome plugin idea. I haven't forgotten though.

Comment: search for advanced code editor plugin :)